Google App Script is not copying the hyperlinks when the rows gets moved from one tab to another -
I need all my hyperlinks cells to copy over to the tabs once it's moved -
My client needs to be able to go back to that linked tab when it's moved from "open" to "delivered"
I'm not a pro but this is my current script - not sure what I am doing wrong:
function onEdit(e){
let col = range.getColumn();
let row = range.getRow();
let val = range.getValue();
let source = e.source.getActiveSheet();

if (col == 9 && val != ''){
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(source.getName());
let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(val);
let data = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getRichTextValues();
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,data[0].length).setRichTextValues(data);
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(),1).clearContent();
  sheet.deleteRow(row);
 }
 }

It copies the rest of the row but now the cell with the hyperlink-
Thank you!
I haven't tried much to edit the script as I am not sure where the error is happening as nothing shows incorrectly when I run it

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly share a  minimal, reproducible example that copies the rest of the row but now the cell with the hyperlink.

@Saddles once i move the rows by criteria the original row values just copies "rich text values" to the new tab

Please don't add comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

If you wish to copy the formatting of the cell to show the hyperlink when they're moved over, you may use the copyTo(destination) method.

Retain the Format of Hyperlink Using copyTo
Just like what @Saddles said, you may use copyTo if you wish to keep the HyperLink format when it moved to the other Google Sheet tab.
I modified and deleted some of your codes to come up with your desired output.

I changed this code:
let data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getRichTextValues();

to:
let data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());

And replace this code:
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, data[0].length).setRichTextValues(data);
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 1).clearContent();

with:
data.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: false })


And also, I added e.range to your code.

Full Code:
function onEdit(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  let col = range.getColumn();
  let row = range.getRow();
  let val = range.getValue();
  let source = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if (col == 9 && val != '') {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(source.getName());
    let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(val);
    let data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    data.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: false })
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}

Sample Output:


Note: I just assumed that your sample sheet was like this.

Reference:

copyTo(destination, options)


If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. Feel free to clarify below if this was not the result you want. Kindly provide your sample sheet, with your expected output so that we can further help you.

You're welcome! Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer.
